# What I need to add to email body for support tags in google email?

Tags: html, email

I want to know what special tags/element/use special HTML formats  (maybe term is wrong)  should I add/use to my email, for say google to show "View order","Traking","Email" or any other special mark near mail title ? see my image for details make it clear.
[image: tags]

Thanks for explanation

Comment: Looks like google interprets html markup in message subjects? That should be a huge security issue, strange. I suggest you simply take a look yourself using your browsers development console to find out the code of such subject and then make an attempt yourself.

Comment: I strongly believe some special format should exist. Yes google went throw page text for it. But not all emails with some track or other information have this link.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot make sense of your last comment. What do you mean by "google went throw page text for it"? What do you mean by "some track or other information"? HTML is a well defined markup language. There are no hidden, magical tags kept secret.

Comment: sorry for made some mess for you. You mention that google interprets html markup. They defiantly does. But I need to know on with tags or attributes google decide to show extra link (like on image). I mean, for example, then you purchased some tickets, or goods and get email about it, google can handle it

Comment: I said that this looks like they interpret html markup in the subject, which is _not_ common. It is obvious that most email visualizing code is able to interpret markup in the body, of course. Although I never really understood why one needs html markup in something as simple as an email message. If they do, then isn't that simply a question of coding an html button in the subject? Why do you claim google implements some magical logic that guesses some link and that a button should be shown? Is there any reason why you believe so?